# IntelliJ Community - React.js support

Tags: javascript, reactjs, intellij-idea

Can someone recommend a free plugin for React.js (i.e. syntax highlighting, autocomplete) one can use in IntelliJ Community edition? My Ultimate license is ending and I want to migrate to Community. I know there exist some relevant answers on stackoverflow, but none of them is satisfactory (I would like to use the same IDE and not change it). Thanks!

Comment: React is not supported in the community version of the IDE. What about WebStorm, which is almost 4x cheaper than IntelliJ Ultimate?

Comment: Yes, I just downloaded it, maybe it's the way... Or just use Intellij Community for Java and VisualStudio for Javascript...

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript support cannot be added to IJ IDEA Community Edition. The required plugins are only available in the Ultimate edition, and there are no free alternatives.

If you can't afford IDEA Ultimate, try [WebStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/features/): it provides advanced coding assistance for Angular and React out of the box, and is [less expensive](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/buy/#personal?billing=yearly).